# FTP not working but telnet works

Tags: ftp

I am not able to login to FTP using my FTP client. But I am able to login to FTP using telnet.

I can't see any errors in my vsftp logs.

Any help?

Comment: It would help greatly if you described the symptoms (e.g. "it hangs forever on connect attempt", "I get No-such-user", "421 Server not available").

Answer (score 0):

FTP uses TCP Port 22 for transfering command. It uses additional TCP ports to transport file, these ports may be blocked by your firewall.

Also try to set your FTP-Client in "passive mode".

Comment: You mean port 21.